# Channel compression in IBM MQ classes for Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

How can I implement a data compression plan other than RLE,ZLIBFAST or ZLIBHIGH for channel compression in IBM MQ using Java classes?

There are several algorithms like Lempel,DEFLATE and Huffman coding for data compression.Can I use these algorithms for my implementation?

Comment: You could compress the message body you are sending.  Make sure give the message a format of MQFMT_NONE so that the conversion is not attempted.  You may have issues if this is sent between platforms of different types (ex: ASCII vs EBCDIC).  In this case the receiving app would also need to know to uncompress the message it receives.

Comment: If you want to do end-to-end compress, where both ends are Java applications then have a look at the open source project Universal File Mover: http://capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html  It has code to compress the message before it is sent (UFM as sender) and it has code to decompress the message on reception (UFM as a receiver).  Note: You will still have the ASCII to EBCDIC issue as JoshMc pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use the builtin compress features because otherwise you will need to write send and receive exits for MQ.  You will need above average programming skills and a very strong knowledge of MQ to do this.

Yes, you can write the client-side in Java but the server-side must be written in C or Assembler!

Once you go down this path, are you prepared to support other client-side platforms?  i.e. native (C or COBOL), .NET, C++, etc..

Also, application messages are segmented into 32KB chunks. All segments that move between the client-side and server-side (and vice versa) are prefix with a TSH header.  IBM does not document the TSH structure because they don't want people messing with it.  Although, Wire Shark has done a good job of interpreting it (except for the new TSHC & TSHM headers).

There is absolutely nothing simple about your question.  I know because I have written a lot of MQ exits.